# How can I have the indices of the string 'OFF' from the given list. I tried to loop through the list with an if statement but I was unsuccessful

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

How can I have the indices of the string 'OFF' from the given list. I tried to loop through the list with an if statement but I was unsuccessful

```
New_Layer_list =[[6], [1], [1, 3, ':OFF', 7, ':OFF', 8, 9], [1, 3, 7, ':OFF', 8, 9, 0, 6]]
OFF_index_list = []
for i in New_Layer_list:
    for j in i:
        if j == ':OFF':
            OFF_index_list.append(i.index(j))
        else:
            pass
print(OFF_index_list)
# [2, 2, 3]
```

I don't understand why it gives me OFF_index_list = [2, 2, 3] and not [2, 4, 3] which is what I expect

Comment: `'OFF'` isn't the same as `':OFF'` and your code is testing for equality

Comment: @nick How are you going to use `OFF_index_list` when you don't know which inner list the indexes come from?

Comment: @ekhumoro, Good question! but My main concern is to understand what is wrong with my way of writing loop and if statement. When I understand it I know I can extract the indices of the inner list. That is noworries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the expression `i.index(j)`. This method returns the *lowest* index in `i` where the element `j` occurs; so even on the second occurrence of `j`, it returns the index of the first occurrence.

Note that you only call it when `j == ':OFF'`, and `i.index(':OFF')` cannot return a different index each time you call it on the same list `i`.

---

The solution to your problem is the `enumerate` function - you need to iterate over index/value pairs, in order to know the index of the value you're currently looking at.

```py
New_Layer_list =[[6], [1], [1, 3, ':OFF', 7, ':OFF', 8, 9], [1, 3, 7, ':OFF', 8, 9, 0, 6]]
OFF_index_list = []

for lst in New_Layer_list:
    for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
        if val == ':OFF':
            OFF_index_list.append(idx)

print(OFF_index_list)
# [2, 4, 3]
```

I've also neatened up a few other things in the code, such as making the variable names more descriptive, and getting rid of the empty `else` block.